# Asyncstorage React Native getting Item

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to have an app where the user can select a photo, but upon closing and reopening the app, the photo is displayed when they open the app. I'm trying to use AsyncStorage to store the photo information so I can display it when the app reopens. I keep getting an [Object object] so I'm not sure if that's the promise object or just the object from the photo. Even before I save the photo in Asyncstorage, the source seems to be an [Object object] so I am very confused. Here's a bit of my code for context:

```
export default class GroundingBox extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.selectPhotoTapped = this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this);
}


async saveKey(key, value){
value = JSON.stringify(value);
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
  console.log("Error: could not save data" + error);

 }
}

async getKey(key){
try {
  var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
  value = JSON.parse(value);
  return value;
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
}
}

state = {
avatarSource: null,
songTitle: null,
};

async checkPhoto(){
 source = await this.getKey('GroundingPhoto');

 if (source != null){


console.log("This is what source does look like: " + source);

this.setState({
  avatarSource: source
   });
 }
 }


 async checkSongTitle(){

  if (await this.getKey('SongTitle') != null){

   source = await this.getKey('SongTitle');

   //console.log("This is what source does look like: " + source);

   this.setState({
   songTitle: source
  });
}
}


 async selectPhotoTapped() {
  const options = {
   quality: 1.0,
   maxWidth: 500,
   maxHeight: 500,
   storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
        },
   };

 setTimeout(() => {

 ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  } else {
    let source = { uri: response.uri };
   console.log("This is what source should look like: " + source);
    this.setState({
      avatarSource: source,
    });
  }
})
}, 500);

await this.saveKey('GroundingPhoto', this.state.avatarSource);
//console.log("AVATAR:" + this.state.avatarSource);

//TODO: Photo no longer saves upon app close

 }




 render() {

this.checkPhoto();

return (


<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
    <View
            style={[
              styles.avatar,
              styles.avatarContainer,
              { marginBottom: 20 },
            ]}
            >

    {(this.state.avatarSource == null) ? (
      <Button
      type="custom"
      backgroundColor={"#7bd2d8"}
      borderColor={"#16a085"}
      borderRadius={10}
      shadowHeight={5}
      containerStyle={styles.buttonContainer}
      contentStyle={styles.content}
      onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}> Select a Photo </Button>
    ) : (
      <Image style={styles.avatar} source={this.state.avatarSource} />
    )}

    </View>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the data you are storing?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, it's just the file path of the picture I would assume

Comment: Just `console.log(value)` before `value = JSON.stringify(value);`

Comment: {"uri":"file:///Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57E2A513-46C1-4CFD-8991-37D1759D06E7/data/Containers/Data/Application/700D19F4-F711-4A93-A676-99C6F7AF8E34/Documents/669B9671-5FD1-423E-A8B8-0075E1954C97.jpg"}

Comment: On your `setState` set `avatarSource: source.uri` instead of just `avatarSource: source` and tell me if it works

Comment: that didn't work. I'm still getting the same issue where the button shows up instead of a photo

Comment: But works when the photo shows up?

Comment: No it does not work

Answer (score 0):

the setState function doesn't instantly change the state. Therefore you cannot simply do this:

```
this.setState({avatarSource: source});
await this.saveKey('GroundingPhoto', this.state.avatarSource);
```

Moreover, in the current implementation, the `saveKey()` gets executed before the avatarSource can be set

instead, simply do this:

```
this.setState({avatarSource: source});
this.saveKey('GroundingPhoto', source);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still didn't fix the issue where the picture is not there upon reopen. I'm not sure why that's still happening. It simply shows the "Select Photo" button upon reopen

Answer (score 0):

I went through the documentation for react-native-image-picker and found [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker#notes)

> On iOS, don't assume that the absolute uri returned will persist. See
>   [#107](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/107)

Although #107 proposes a bunch of solutions, if I were you, I would rather go with storing the base64 of the image, and then retrieve it back